# Redis-om search cannot find key after updating

Tags: node.js, database, redis, beta

I have some strange behaviour happening with my Redis-OM application, I understand that this is still a very BETA version of the software but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something dumb (which I might be)

So I am setting up an application to keep a playlist of video ID's within a Room that I store temporarily in a Redis Cloud Database.

I have a function that creates a Room, one that fetches the Room details (everything currently in the room) and one that adds a new video to the Playlist within that room. (*see below*) - NOTE: the data variable within `createRoom(data)` is just a string of the Room ID

```js
class Room extends Entity {}
let schema = new Schema(
    Room,
    {
        code: { type: 'string' },
        playlist: {
            type: 'array',
            videos: {
                type: 'object',
            },
        },
    },
    {
        dataStructure: 'JSON',
    }
);

export async function createRoom(data) {
    await connect();

    const repository = new Repository(schema, client);

    const room = repository.createEntity(data);

    const id = await repository.save(room);

    await client.execute(['EXPIRE', `Room:${id}`, 43200]);

    return id;
}

export async function getRoom(code) {
    await connect();

    const repository = new Repository(schema, client);

    const room = await repository
        .search()
        .where('code')
        .equals(code)
        .returnFirst();

    return room;
}

export async function addVideoToRoom(code, videoDetails) {
    const room = await getRoom(code);
    await room.playlist.push(videoDetails);

    await connect();

    const repository = new Repository(schema, client);

    const id = await repository.save(room);

    return id;
}
```

The primary issue that I'm having is adding a second video to the playlist. What happens is

- Create Room - adds a new room to the DB
- Search for video
- Click to add video to DB (video is successfully added)
- Click to add second video to DB (fails because `getRoom(code)`fails - returns null)

This was working yesterday, however I'm not sure why it no longer works.

If anyone has any idea's why that might be please let me know, I have a feeling it may be how I'm handling clients or indexes with Redis so I have popped my functions for those below too.

```js
const client = new Client();

async function connect() {
    if (!client.isOpen()) {
        await client.open(process.env.REDIS_URL);
    }
}

export async function createIndex() {
    await connect();

    const repository = new Repository(schema, client);

    await repository.dropIndex();

    await repository.createIndex();
}
```

Thanks very much programmers of Stack - If I'm being super dumb I do apologise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis OM for Node.js supports neither nested objects nor a type of 'object' within the Schema. Valid types are 'string', 'number', 'boolean', and 'array'. Arrays are only arrays of strings. The rest are self-explanatory.

If you want to have a Room that has multiple Videos, you need to define a Room entity, perhaps with a playlist that is defined as an array not of objects, but of Video ids.

Details on this can be found in the [README](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-node#-define-an-entity-and-a-schema).

Comment: Ah okay, thanks very much @Guy Royse!

Comment: Thanks for using Redis OM!

Comment: Hi Royse, good to see you.
Thanks for contribution of this library.

Comment: Can I use this library with Vanilla js (not typescript)? because you mentioned typescript inside the document .

Comment: Works just fine with vanilla JavaScript. In fact, that's how I usually use it.